# what reasons would you give regarding the unsuitability of butter for deep frying?

Tags: butter

If a student brought butter to your class for use for deep frying food, what reasons would you give regarding the unsuitability of butter for deep frying?

Comment: what kind of class?

Answer (score 0):

The milk solids in the butter will burn and render the butter bitter and whatever you want to dry.

Best fix would be to clarify the butter to remove the milk solids.

Answer (score 0):

The smoke point of non-clarified butter is 300F (149 C)...ghee (clarified butter) eliminates the milk solids and gets you to a smoke point of about 482F (250 C).  So, your student my not be wrong, depending on whether or not the butter is clarified.